# Missing Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter while setting up WiFi hotspot in Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, wifi-configuration

I've recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

I'm using my computer as a WiFi hotspot, and I can't get that to work in Windows 10.

First, I'm setting up the network:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=[name] key=[password]
```

I'm trying to start the network:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

> The hosted network couldn't be started.
>   The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.

Investigating a little, I saw that I need to enable "Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter" on the Device Manager, but it is not there.

Next, I tried

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```

```
Interface name: Wi-Fi

    Driver                    : Dell Wireless 1704 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHz)
    Vendor                    : Broadcom
    Provider                  : Broadcom
    Date                      : 30/07/2015
    Version                   : 7.35.295.0
    INF file                  : C:\WINDOWS\INF\oem162.inf
    Files                     : 4 total
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\bcmwl63a.sys
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcmihvsrv64.dll
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\bcmihvui64.dll
                                C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\vwifibus.sys
    Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
    Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
    FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
    802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
    Hosted network supported  : No
    Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                                Open            None
                                Open            WEP
                                WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                                WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                                WPA-Personal    TKIP
                                WPA-Personal    CCMP
                                WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                                WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                                WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                                WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                                Vendor defined  Vendor defined
    IHV service present       : Yes
    IHV adapter OUI           : [00 10 18], type: [00]
    IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcmihvsrv64.dll
    IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {aaa6dee9-31b9-4f18-ab39-82ef9b06eb73}
    IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
```

I have `Hosted network supported  : No` - which I think is the cause of my problem.

How can I fix this issue? Did anything change in Windows 10?

Comment: If it *used* to work in 8 and doesnt worked in 10 then we know HW support is present and thus its a driver issue. Remove the driver completely and manually grab the latest from dell.

Comment: I have the same issue with `7.35.295.0` driver version, which is proposed by Windows 10 Update. The default version `6.3.x` is OK, but the new one, which Windows 10 downloads automatically breaks the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by updating the drivers, like the comment suggested.

In my very specific case, for Dell Inspiron 3721, I found the drivers at http://downloads.dell.com/published/pages/inspiron-17-3721.html#Drivers , under Dell Wireless 1704 WiFi Driver.

Comment: I also updated the Realtek sound driver and now it doesn't sound like a radio.

Comment: Another note: I had to reinstall the drivers after a major Windows update.

Comment: This stopped working after the Windows 10 Anniversary Update. Here's a related question: [Internet Connection Sharing stopped working after Windows 10 Anniversary Update](http://superuser.com/q/1110866/1838)

Comment: I bought a modem router. ☹

Answer (score 5):

I restored my old WiFi driver using the steps found [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/restore-driver-previous-version#1TC=windows-7) because my new one was breaking the hosted network functionality.

> **To restore a driver to its previous version**
>
> You must be logged on as an administrator to perform these steps.
>
> 1. Open Device Manager by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking System and Security,
>      and then, under System, clicking Device Manager. Administrator
>      permission required If you're prompted for an administrator password
>      or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.‌
> 2. Double-click the category containing your device driver, and then double-click the name of the device that you want to restore to a
>      previous driver version.
> 3. Click the Driver tab, and then click Roll Back Driver.
>
> If you are logged on as a standard user, the button will be dimmed,
>   which means it's unavailable. You must be logged on as an
>   administrator to roll back a driver.

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include how you restored it? We prefer the details be put here, as opposed to just linking

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Once it worked for me in Windows 10.

1. Go to Device Manager.
2. Go to Properties of Wi-Fi Adapter.
3. On *Properties* dialog box, Click on *Advanced* option tab at the top.
4. Inside the *Property* list, click on *HT mode*.
5. Then set the box below the *Value* to *Enabled*.
6. Click the *OK* button.

After that check the hosted network mode by cmd command.

```
 netsh wlan show drivers
```

If the hostednetwork supported = "yes" then Your problem is solved. 
After that follow the create hostednetwork process using cmd command.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For me I　get same error when I tried to execute `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`. I solved it by set `EnableAdaptivity` as `Enable`.

My wifi card is RTL8192CU.  I could not find `Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter` either, even though I update my driver. But I have **Hosted network supported  : Yes**. There is no `HT mode` in my wifi adapter's **Property** list. But I have **EnableAdaptivity** option in the list and I set it as `Enable`. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` just works, at same time I still did not find `Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter`.

Comment: Where now do you set Enable Adaptivity?

Comment: in my wifi adapter's **Property** list

Answer (score 0):

Manually changing to a different WiFi driver version fixed the issue for me. Here are the steps to change the Wifi Driver version,

1.Open device manager

2.Go to network adapters

3.Now right click on your wireless adapter and click on update driver software

4.Then click on browse my computer.....

5.Then click on "let me pick from a list...."

6.Finally u will see a list of drivers and their versions. Just double click on the oldest version.(Mostly it should be listed in the top with no date of release in it)

7.It will install and the virtual adapter will show up when u refresh it.

Answer (score -2):

Installing the Microsoft hosted Virtual Adapter will solve your problem. That particular adapter can create a WiFi hotspot in Windows.

Comment: How? Details/steps would improve this answer.