# Can a computer with one Wi-Fi adapter both connect to a Wi-Fi network and share Internet over Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows, macos, wireless-networking, terminology, internet-sharing

I will explain my use case but I am asking about what is technically available with Wi-Fi technology, so please don't submit alternative solutions as answers.

I have a MacBook Air and a cheap Windows netbook, each with Wi-Fi.

My home Internet is provided via Wi-Fi with a captive portal that only allows me to long on with one device.

I want to be able to use both the Windows and Mac laptops on the Wi-Fi Internet provided where I live.

When I ask non-technical people about this they all seem to think it's not possible. I'm technical but I suck at networking.

A Wi-Fi adapter can obviously both send and receive so there doesn't seem to be a hardware reason this is not possible. But perhaps the Wi-Fi networking protocols were not designed with such a possibility taken into account?

So can Wi-Fi technically solve this problem? If so what terminology is used for this so I can read up on it? If not, what are the limiting factors that prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to connect the Wifi with your Windows PC.
And if you have windows 7 or above you can share the wifi from your windows with a "hostednetwork".

This will create a new Hotspot an your WindowsPC, and you can connect your Mac to this Hotspot.

Try these commands, this will create a new Hotspot on you WindowsPC:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=YOUR_NEW_HOTSPOT_NAME key=YOUR_HOTSPOT_PASSWORD
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Run the following Commands to disable the Hotspot:

```
netsh wlan stop hostednetwork
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=disallow
```

Here is a step by step tuturial. It`s in german, I hope it helps anyway.

Tuturial: http://praxistipps.chip.de/wlan-hotspot-unter-windows-7-erstellen-so-gehts_9939

Comment: The first command to create the Hotspot succeeds. The second fails with `The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.` Could this be because I only have Windows 10 Starter or is there something I can tweak to get it to work?

Comment: @hippietrail [Fix The Hosted Network Couldn’t be Started Error in Windows 10](http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-the-hosted-network-couldnt-be-started-error-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Please check if your network card is enabled.

Or check this question for more information.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork

Comment: @Radon8472: The network card is enabled. I'm writing this comment via it (-;

Comment: @DavidPostill: At step 5 I have no `Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter` in my expanded Network adapters section. In Fix 3 I have no Power Management tab for my wireless network adapter.

Comment: I have tried restarting the computer and Showing hidden devices. I do have a "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter" - could that be the same thing with another name?

Comment: Try the command:

`netsh interface show interface`

to display the state of your interfaces.
But you should the the new HotSpot-Adapter in "adapter settings" in exporer.

Go to "network and sharing center" and click to "change adapter settings"

Comment: @Radon8472: Sorry I can't find anything about HotSpot adapter in "change adapter settings". When I try the command you suggest the result is: Admin State=Enabled State=Connected Type=Dedicated Interface Name=Wi-Fi.

Comment: There is a specific SuperUser question about this problem and I'm going through it now: [Missing Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter while setting up WiFi hotspot in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/982364)